# Hive Job is processing is stopped after processing sometime

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, hiveql, hadoop2, apache-hive

I am running hive on a standalone machine. Hadoop is running in pseudo-distributed mode. I am running hive query which joins two tables (one table has 7M and another has 51M records and each containing 8 columns). After processing some time, Mapper reaches to zero percentage and then continues to print zero occasionally. Can you please help me to resolve this.

For reference find the logs below.

```
2016-04-12 22:52:58,469 Stage-1 map = 71%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:00,517 Stage-1 map = 72%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:02,560 Stage-1 map = 73%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:09,740 Stage-1 map = 74%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:11,796 Stage-1 map = 75%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:13,842 Stage-1 map = 76%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:21,037 Stage-1 map = 77%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:24,114 Stage-1 map = 78%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:26,156 Stage-1 map = 79%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:35,433 Stage-1 map = 81%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:38,507 Stage-1 map = 82%,  reduce = 1%
2016-04-12 22:53:45,725 Stage-1 map = 82%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-12 22:53:49,925 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-12 22:54:50,236 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-12 22:55:50,546 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-12 22:56:50,863 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-12 22:57:51,128 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-12 22:58:51,352 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-12 22:59:51,612 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-12 23:00:51,886 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-12 23:01:52,131 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
```

I verified the status in the tracker. The status was showing two attemps and one attempt was failed with the diagnostic message as follows.

```
AM Container for appattempt_1460481465127_0001_000001 exited with exitCode: -100
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1460481465127_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* nodeFailing this attempt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by Heap space on the map side. 
 Try to increase the map task heap size by doing the following:

in `mapred-site.xml` (Try to tune the following values to match with your use case):

```
<!-- for mappers -->
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
   <value>4096</value>
</property>
<!-- For reduces -->
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
   <value>8192</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate about how did you got to this conclusion?

Comment: @Nimrod I checked that in the logs of the mappers, and I ve had seen the OOM exceptions there